# Check if the password is correct using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a database that the user can create an account for with an id being auto generated and the password being users inputted.

I then on another page need to check if the password is correct, and I have the id in a drop down so I don't have to check for that. How would I do this?

I have the password and the id in the same MySQL table, and I am using PHP to grab stuff from the table.

How I connect to the database:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=courses;dbname=cs56711";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
```

I have tried a bunch of different ideas on how to try this, but none have worked so far. That's also why I don't have more code, because I have changed things out so much that I don't think anything would help it.

Comment: You should be using `password_hash()` when you store the password in the database, and `password_verify()` to check the password.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Barmar would that be in the php or html? I am very rusty on both of them

Comment: So you only have a PDO connection? I'm sorry, but your question is too broad and unclear. You must make attempts to solve it your self first. Then, If you run into _specific_ issues with your _existing_ code, come back, show us the attempt and we can help you sort it out, but we won't write it all for you.

Comment: @AScheel Those are PHP functions, look up the documentation.

Comment: @Barmar I just looked at the doc and I think that could work. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-password-hash

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check a value in different pages, use Session values. Store the password as a session value and you can compare it with the database value then.

*Important*: Do not store the plain text password always; **always** use hashed values. You can either use `password_hash()`, `sha1`, or any other method.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Hashing entered password
    $hashedPass = password_hash($userPass , PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    // Save your password value in session variable
    $_SESSION['userpass'] = $hashedPass;

    if( isset( $_SESSION['userpass'] ) ) {
       // Here you can compare the values
    }
    else {
       echo "password value is empty"
    }
```